# Summarize variable for different time periods and by group using ddply

Tags: r, plyr, summarization

I am trying to summarize a sales report by client and get the total sales for different periods of time:

```
   Client   Q   Sales   Date
   A    2   30  01/01/2014
   A    3   24  02/01/2014
   A    1   10  03/01/2014
   B    4   10  01/01/2014
   B    1   20  02/01/2014
   B    3   30  03/01/2014
```

I am able to summarize by client using `ddply`:

```
 rapport <- ddply(df, CLIENT, summarise, 
           Q = sum(Q), 
           Sales = sum(Sales) )

   Client   Q   Sales   
   A        6   64  
   B        7   60
```

I would like to add an extra column with sales only for the date 03/01/2014

```
Client   Q  Sales  Sales03/01/2014
   A     6  64      10
   B     7  60      30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DF <- read.table(text="   Client   Q   Sales   Date
   A    2   30  01/01/2014
   A    3   24  02/01/2014
   A    1   10  03/01/2014
   B    4   10  01/01/2014
   B    1   20  02/01/2014
   B    3   30  03/01/2014", header=TRUE)

library(plyr)
ddply(DF, .(Client), summarise, 
      Q = sum(Q), 
      `Sales03/01/2014` = Sales[Date=="03/01/2014"],
      Sales = sum(Sales))

#  Client Q Sales03/01/2014 Sales
#1      A 6              10    64
#2      B 8              30    60
```

Note that order of evaluation is important here if you want the same name for output as for input `Sales`. Also, it is best to avoid names that are not valid syntax.

Comment: Hi I am receiving an error message. Below is the code for my real data frame:    rapport<-ddply(df, .(PRODUCT, GROUPE), summarise, 
               QSoldFiscal = sum(QTY.SHIPPED), 
               DSold3M = PRE.TAX.TOTAL.[INVOICE.DATE > M7],
               DSoldFiscal = sum(PRE.TAX.TOTAL.) )                        Error: length(rows) == 1 is not TRUE (ERROR MESSage). Do you know how to correct this

Comment: There is more than one `INVOICE.DATE > M7`. `summarise` expects exactly one value.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve the same result using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>%
  group_by(Client) %>%
  summarise(SumOfQ = sum(Q) 
            `Sales03/01/2014` = Sales[Date=="03/01/2014"],
            SumOfSales = sum(Sales))
```

`dplyr` is slower for the example case, but much faster for large data frames.